# Fade in animation sprite using nav dt

Tags: css, navigation, fadein, sprite-sheet

I want to create a fade-in effect to my sprite buttons in the navigation menu I made. I want the fade-in time to match the icons at the bottom of the website, but I can't seem to apply the same thing to my navigation. It will just change instantly. Even if I did it successfully, the sprites will just do a slide effect, which is not what I want. I only want it done in CSS. Can you help me out?

Here is my website: [www.thestripedphoenix.com](http://www.thestripedphoenix.com/)

```css
#navigation {
  position: relevant;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 800px;
  max-width: 600px;
  min-width: 520px;
  height: 50px;
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#nav {
  position: relevant;
  right: 0.5em;
  height: 49px;
  line-height: 3em;
  border: 3px solid #232323;
}
#nav dl {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#nav dt {
  float: left;
}
#nav dt a {
  display: block;
  height: 0px !important;
  padding: 100px 0 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#nav dt a:hover {
  background: 0 -50px;
}
#nav dt a:active {
  background-position: 0 -50px;
}
#nav dt a:visited {
  background-position: 0 -50px;
}
#nav dt#start, #nav dt#start a {
  width: 100px;
  background-image: url("http://www.thestripedphoenix.com/images/intro.gif");
}
#nav dt#about, #nav dt#about a {
  width: 100px;
  background-image: url("http://www.thestripedphoenix.com/images/about.gif");
}
#nav dt#skills, #nav dt#skills a {
  width: 100px;
  background-image: url("http://www.thestripedphoenix.com/images/skills.gif");
}
#nav dt#portfolio, #nav dt#portfolio a {
  width: 100px;
  background-image: url("http://www.thestripedphoenix.com/images/portfolio.gif");
}
#nav dt#message, #nav dt#message a {
  width: 100px;
  background-image: url("http://www.thestripedphoenix.com/images/contact.gif");
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
  <nav id="nav">
    <dl>
      <dt id="start"><a href="#intro">intro</a><span></span></dt>
      <dt id="about"><a href="#one">about</a></dt>
      <dt id="skills"><a href="#two">skills</a></dt>
      <dt id="portfolio"><a href="#work">portfolio</a></dt>
      <dt id="message"><a href="#contact">contact</a></dt>
    </dl>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already assigned same background images to `#nav dt` and `#nav dt a` all you have to do now is set `opacity` of `a` to 0 and return it to 1 on hover. Add `transition` for animation. Icons on the bottom of the page are set for 0.2 sec animation. I set menu buttons for 0.25s

```css
#navigation {
  position: relevant;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 800px;
  max-width: 600px;
  min-width: 520px;
  height: 50px;
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #232323;
}
#nav {
  position: relevant;
  right: 0.5em;
  height: 49px;
  line-height: 3em;
  border: 3px solid #232323;
}
#nav dl {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#nav dt {
  float: left;
}
#nav dt a {
  display: block;
  height: 0px !important;
  padding: 100px 0 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: all 0.25s;
}
#nav dt a:active {
  background-position: 0 -50px;
}
#nav dt a:visited {
  background-position: 0 -50px;
}
#nav dt#start, #nav dt#start a {
  width: 100px;
  background-image: url("http://www.thestripedphoenix.com/images/intro.gif");
}
#nav dt#about, #nav dt#about a {
  width: 100px;
  background-image: url("http://www.thestripedphoenix.com/images/about.gif");
}
#nav dt#skills, #nav dt#skills a {
  width: 100px;
  background-image: url("http://www.thestripedphoenix.com/images/skills.gif");
}
#nav dt#portfolio, #nav dt#portfolio a {
  width: 100px;
  background-image: url("http://www.thestripedphoenix.com/images/portfolio.gif");
}
#nav dt#message, #nav dt#message a {
  width: 100px;
  background-image: url("http://www.thestripedphoenix.com/images/contact.gif");
}
#nav dt a {
  background: 0 -50px;
  opacity: 0;
}
#nav dt a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
  <nav id="nav">
    <dl>
      <dt id="start"><a href="#intro">intro</a></dt>
      <dt id="about"><a href="#one">about</a></dt>
      <dt id="skills"><a href="#two">skills</a></dt>
      <dt id="portfolio"><a href="#work">portfolio</a></dt>
      <dt id="message"><a href="#contact">contact</a></dt>
    </dl>
  </nav>
</div>
```